# How to query for the object message__c in my program?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

a lot of you might find my question really basic but I am beginner. I am writing a visualforce page and here is my code.

```
public class CustomControllerExtension1 {
    public Account accountOfInterest{get;set;}
    public contact contactOfInterest{get;set;}
    public CustomControllerExtension1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        accountOfInterest = (account)(controller.getRecord());
        contactOfInterest = [select name, id from contact where id='00341000003a3gV'];

    }

    public void SaveCustom() {
      if(accountOfInterest.monthly__c<10000) {
           upsert accountOfInterest;

          } else { 
                    accountOfInterest.monthly__c=10000; 
                    accountOfInterest.message__c='Salary is more than permitted!';

                 }

    }
}
```

When I am trying to save the code its asking me to query Message object. When I queried separately as in "select message_c from account" it gives me error saying an another for the query of the same object had been found and doesn't let me run it. Please help. If needed I will provide more information and screenshots. 
Thank you.

Comment: can you post the exact error message, may be someone can take a look at it and help

Comment: Have changed my answer - hopefully it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your page, add the field that you want to reference, but don't render it.

```
<apex:outputText rendered="false" value="{!Account.message__c}"/>
```

Also, I can see another error. You are assigning the result of the SOQL query to a single `sObject` when you should be assigning it to a list. An alternative is to use a `LIMIT 1` clause, but that causes errors if a record is not found.

Given that, change your  code to this:

```
Contact[] contacts = [select name, id from contact where id='00341000003a3gV']; 
//note, you should probably not be hardcoding an id here
if (!contacts.isEmpty()){
    contactOfInterest = contacts[0]; 
}
```